# saving imageView into database

Tags: android, android-intent, android-studio, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I would want to save the image on my imageview onto a database but I am unable to save the image on my imageview into the database.

**MainActivity.java**

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE:
                if (data != null) {
                    int id = dbHandler.getEntriesCount();
                    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    SimpleDateFormat dayTime = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
                    String date = dayTime.format(new Date(time));
                    String title = data.getStringExtra("Title");
                    String passage = data.getStringExtra("Passage");
                    Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(data.getStringExtra("imageUri"));
                    Entry entry = new Entry(id, title, passage, imageUri, date);
                    dbHandler.createEntry(entry);
                    Entry Entry = dbHandler.getEntry(id);
                    entryList.add(Entry);
                    EntryListadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**Acitivity_Write.Java**

```
SaveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent data = new Intent();
            data.putExtra("Title", TitleTxt.getText().toString());
            data.putExtra("Passage", WriteTxt.getText().toString());
            data.putExtra("imageUri", Uri.parse(EntryImgImageView.toString()));
            setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
            finish();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Entry Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

**Entry.Java**

```
public class Entry {

public String _title, _passage;
public Uri _imageUri;
public String _date;
public int _id;

public Entry (int id, String title, String passage, Uri imageUri, String date) {
    _id = id;
    _title = title;
    _passage = passage;
    _imageUri = imageUri;
    _date = date;
}

public int getId() { return _id; }
public String getTitle() { return _title; }
public String getPassage() { return _passage; }
public Uri getImageUri() { return  _imageUri; }
public String getDate() { return _date; }
}
```

**DatabaseHandler.java**

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "entriesManager",
TABLE_ENTRIES = "entries",
KEY_ID = "id",
KEY_TITLE = "title",
KEY_PASSAGE = "passage",
KEY_IMAGEURI = "imageUri",
KEY_DATE="date";


public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ENTRIES + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_TITLE + " TEXT," + KEY_PASSAGE + " TEXT," + KEY_IMAGEURI + " URI," + KEY_DATE + " TEXT)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ENTRIES);

    onCreate(db);
}

public void createEntry(Entry entry) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();


    values.put(KEY_ID,entry.getId());
    values.put(KEY_TITLE, entry.getTitle());
    values.put(KEY_PASSAGE, entry.getPassage());
    values.put(KEY_IMAGEURI, entry.getImageUri().toString());
    values.put(KEY_DATE, entry.getDate());

    db.insert(TABLE_ENTRIES, null, values);
    db.close();
}
```

**Error**

> 12-16 03:11:09.210 3217-3217/unipersonalinc.mypersonalediary E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   12-16 03:11:09.210 3217-3217/unipersonalinc.mypersonalediary E/AndroidRuntime: Process: unipersonalinc.mypersonalediary, PID: 3217
>   12-16 03:11:09.210 3217-3217/unipersonalinc.mypersonalediary E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering
>   result ResultInfo{who=null, request=100, result=-1, data=Intent { (has
>   extras) }} to activity
>   {unipersonalinc.mypersonalediary/unipersonalinc.mypersonalediary.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
>   12-16 03:11:09.210 3217-3217/unipersonalinc.mypersonalediary E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3699)
>   12-16 03:11:09.210 3217-3217/unipersonalinc.mypersonalediary E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742)
>   12-16 03:11:09.210 3217-3217/unipersonalinc.mypersonalediary E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
>   12-16 03:11:09.210 3217-3217/unipersonalinc.mypersonalediary E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393)
>   12-16 03:11:09.210 3217-3217/unipersonalinc.mypersonalediary E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   12-16 03:11:09.210 3217-3217/unipersonalinc.mypersonalediary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>   12-16 03:11:09.210 3217-3217/unipersonalinc.mypersonalediary E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>   12-16 03:11:09.210 3217-3217/unipersonalinc.mypersonalediary E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native
>   Method)
>   12-16 03:11:09.210 3217-3217/unipersonalinc.mypersonalediary E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>   12-16 03:11:09.210 3217-3217/unipersonalinc.mypersonalediary E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>   12-16 03:11:09.210 3217-3217/unipersonalinc.mypersonalediary E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException:
>   uriString
>   12-16 03:11:09.210 3217-3217/unipersonalinc.mypersonalediary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.net.Uri$StringUri.
>
> 12-16 03:11:09.210 3217-3217/unipersonalinc.mypersonalediary E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: What is `EntryImgImageView` from `EntryImgImageView.toString()`? you got `NullPointerException` with this line. So, try to change `EntryImgImageView.toString()` with your image path `(Uri)`

Comment: Without knowing what EntryImageView is, I cannot give you a clear answer. If the image you are talking about is loaded from the internet, you need to save it as a file on external / internal storage and save the path (uri) to it on the database

Comment: have you solved this problem ? or still there is some issue left ?

Answer (score 0):

The proper way of saving Images is not inside the database. Save the name of the image in database and write the Image in app directory with the same name.

To Retrieve the image Read the image with the name and set that to your `ImageView`.